# Looping in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a do-while loop in bash, and it runs the body once but no more.

```
while read id; do
    bash ./setup_instance.sh "${id}" 
    echo "Ran setup_instance"
done < ids.txt
echo "Finished of loop"
```

The file `ids.txt` has two lines, one "ID" string per line. I tested this by replacing the line inside the loop with echo `"ID: ${id}"` and the loop works.

Also, note that the code does get to the two echo lines, so it is not the case that invoking the script throws us out of the execution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `setup_instance.sh` actually finish, or does it keep running in an endless loop perhaps? (The code shown looks good to me, and works correctly for me if `setup_instance.sh` is filled with some dummy code, that's why I am suspecting `setup_instance.sh` to be the culprit.)

Comment: If you get the echo to work twice, then the body is being run twice. What does `setup_instance.sh` do? What is the behaviour you're expecting to get?

Comment: Is it possible that `setup_instance` is consuming all the input so that there is nothing for the second invocation of `read` to read? (For example, if it invokes `ssh` without `-n`.) Try redirecting its stdin from `/dev/null`.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, `setup_instance.sh` finishes, and as mentioned, the `echo` statements show what happened.

Comment: @WimLewis, yes, there was `ssh` without `-n`. How do I redirect `stdin` from `dev/null`? Like this: `</dev/null` ? And will that disrupt all piping actions in the script?

Comment: @WImLewis, your comment hit it correctly. I resolved this by assigning file contents to an array and iterating over that rather than iterating over input as in the OP code sample.
`
readarray a <_instances.txt
for id in "${a[@]}"; do
     bash ./setup_instance.sh "${id}" 
done`

Answer (score -1):

When running

```
while read id; do
    echo "Ran setup_instance ${id}"
done < ids.txt
echo "Finished of loop"
```

with ids.txt:

```
abc
bcd
```

I get the expected output (with the two lines).

They is a chance that your last line does not contain a linefeed (`\n`)

Can you check by running `cat -A ids.txt`

It should echo

```
abc$
bcd$
```

If the second dollar is missing, try running `dos2unix ids.txt` to add the missing newline (or add it manually)

Comment: Yes, this echo loop works fine for me. It is the invocation of a script that failes